# Why is this a infinite loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
a = raw_input ("enter a number")
i = 0
numbers = []

while i < a:
    print "At the top i is %d" % i
    numbers.append(i)

    i = i + 1
    print "Numbers now:", numbers
    print "At the bottom i is %d" % i

print "The numbers: "

for num in numbers:
    print num
```

so I'm following lpthw and was just messing with the code, why is it when I use raw_input and enter a number like 6 this loop turns into a infinite loop? shouldn't i = i + 1 be there to stop this from happening?

Comment: Because an integer is always less than a string in Python 2.

Comment: I was wrong about this being the answer, but you *are* mixing tabs and spaces. This is **bad**. I don't know why it runs; maybe this is only a problem in your copy/paste to SO, but be sure you're using only spaces.

Comment: fix indents btw... like that the code will just not even compile.

Comment: Is `i = i + 1` inside the while loop? Please fix your indentation. And it's better to write it as `i += 1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Python 2.7, `raw_input` returns a `str`(string). So when you compare `i < a`, you are comparing an integer with a string and it will [always return `True`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3270689/2670792).

**To fix this**, cast your input to an integer:

```
a = int(raw_input(...))
```

**Note:** As @AshwiniChaudhary commented, comparing (with `<`, `<=`, `>` or `>=`) an integer with a string in Python 3.x will raise an Exception:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: int() <operator> str()
```

Comment: Also mention the fact that such comparison will raise error in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

raw_input return a string. Your variable a is a string and strings are greater than ints in python.
You need to convert **a** to an int:

```
a = int(raw_input("enter a number"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `raw_input`, then `a` will be a string. You need an `int`, for the `i < a` comparision to work as expected. Use `input` instead of `raw_input`.

For future reference, `input` was removed in Python 3 and `raw_input` renamed to `input`, so you will need `int(input (...))` in Py3.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing two things that can lead to the infinite loop.

1. The tabs and spaces are mixed up, python cares about indentation, so make sure that i = i + 1 is aligned with numbers.append(i)
2. The actual reason why it is keeping on going is that when python collects raw_input, it transforms it into a string, not an integer, so the comparison does not work as you'd expect. Change to this and it will work as expected:

a = int(raw_input ("enter a number"))